# Looking for a general solution: How to get notified when a software update is released

Tags: windows, deployment, update

this is a general question about software and i hope this is the right platform for it.
maybe superuser.com is the right place but i will try it here first.
i already searched the net for anwers but didn't find anything usefull.

i have a customer that is using about 300 different applications in his environment.
the computers are all running windows 7. 
we have a packaging workflow and patchmanagement (for windows updates).
product owners, managers etc and everything is fine.

but what we don't have:
**something that notifies us once a new version of a software is released**

currently we check the websites or news articles on a regular basis,
but i don't want to waste human ressources on that task and create some software that saves us the work and time.

i played a bit with tools like the CNET techtracker or allmyapps, but its not what i am looking for (i scans your PC for software and checks it own database for newer versions)

so far i thought of following solution:

- find a URL on the software vendors website which contains the software version for each application
- build a html/rss parser that reads the URLs (with filter criteria)
- notify me about changes e.g. by putting that all in a RSS feed

but this has a few flaws:

- kinda a lot of work finding those URLs
- if the vendor makes weird changes to their website it will break.

how do you guys solve that problem in your environment?

do you have a tool or workflow that handles it?

or do you just wait till a customer demands an update?

please share your ideas, maybe we solve this general problem for us and comming generations :)

Comment: thanks for the recommendations! but the most tools just scan your PC and check for updates for installed software. i maintain a list/report from a software inventory i need checked. so far http://software.informer.com/ looks most promising, i will try that

Comment: ok software informer also scans my own computer. not really usefull in a corporate env

Answer (score 1):

This is not advertisement. But probably this is what you are looking for, as there is no central "marketplace" for software in Windows. Wait for Windows 8 where they try to introduce one.

http://secunia.com/vulnerability_intelligence/

Look around. They also have a corporate software inspector.

Answer (score 0):

[SUMo](http://www.kcsoftwares.com/?sumo) or [Software Informer](http://software.informer.com/) may help